# Dependency Intellij-core pull by capacitor-android:detachedConfiguration2 block by our firewall

Tags: java, android, gradle, groovy, capacitor

I have a problem with capacitor 4 [android] when I try to build my app.
For many securities raisons in the company I'm working for, all repositories are behind a nexus firewall and the firewall blocks intellij-core dependency because it finds these vulnerabilities :

[image: Nexus firewall screenshot]

This dependency is used by these tasks on my project :

- capacitor-filesystem:extractReleaseAnnotations
- capacitor-splash-screen:extractReleaseAnnotations
- capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:extractReleaseAnnotations
- capacitor-camera:extractReleaseAnnotations
- capacitor-android:extractReleaseAnnotations

And here an example of my console log :

```
5: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':capacitor-android:extractReleaseAnnotations'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':capacitor-android:detachedConfiguration2'.
   > Could not download intellij-core-30.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:30.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://si-devops-mirror.****.fr/repository/dl.google.com/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/30.2.1/intellij-core-30.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://si-devops-mirror.****.fr/repository/dl.google.com/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/30.2.1/intellij-core-30.2.1.jar'.
            > 403 forbidden
```

This error comes when I try to build the app  on Android Studio or when I launch the capacitor:run command
*ionic capacitor run --c=release* in my ionic project.

I did a Gradle build scan to get the dependencies graph of my application :

[image: Dependencies graph Gradle]

Latest version of Intellij-core (31.0.0-alpha8) isn't blocked by our firewall, but I don't know how to tell Gradle to use the latest version of this subdependency. I tried to exclude the Intellij-core dependency with this (in build.gradle app) but it does not work :

```
    implementation (project(':capacitor-android')) {
        exclude group: 'com.android.tools.external.com-intellij', module: 'intellij-core'
    }
```

Do you have any idea how to bypass this dependency or how to tell Gradle to use the latest version of this dependancy ?

Comment: The problem was solved by updating Gradle to version 5.1 and Android Gradle to version 7.4.0